# Javascript nesting callback API - out of my league

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to use a callback to encapsulate an API solution as follows:

```html
<html>
    <script>
        function main ( CB ) {
            function msg ( s ) {
                window.alert(s);
            }
            CB();
      }
    </script>
    <script>
        main( function () {
           msg("Hello universe"); // <--here
            } );
    </script>
</html>
```

and Javascript throws an error *"msg is not defined"*. I see the problem, but it's not clear how to fix it. I flailed around a bit, and tried `main.msg(...)` and `this.msg(...)` at the line marked "<--here", but had similar results.

Comment: You have to pass msg to cb

Comment: What do you mean by "*encapsulate an API solution*"? Why do you need `main`? Why not just put `msg` in the global scope? What is your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just needed to:

- In the first half: pass `msg` into `CB()` --> `CB(msg)`
- In the second half: get `msg` as a parameter from `main` --> `main(function (msg) {...`

However since it is already a bit confusing anyway, I think having a function and a parameter later on both named `msg` adds potential confusion.  Also there's no need for two separate `<script>` tags.

Here it is cleaned up a bit, and I renamed some things to help make it more clear

```js
function main (callbackFn) {
  function msgFn(str) {
      window.alert(str);
  }
  callbackFn(msgFn);
}

main(function (myFunc) {
   myFunc("Hello universe");
});
```